# Responding to Opportunity Attacks with Snarling Wolf Stance

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, ranger, opportunity-actions

I have a 5th Level Ranger/Psion playing in a Dungeons and Dragons 4e Eberron campaign.

The other day, we had a situation come up in a fight and I want to see if we handled it right. I had Snarling Wolf Stance active, was moving past an enemy, and triggered an opportunity attack. Snarling Wolf Stance says:

> Effect: Until the stance ends, whenever an enemy hits or misses you with a close or a melee attack, you can make a melee basic attack against it as an opportunity action. You can then shift 3 squares, but must not end the shift adjacent to any enemy.

The attacker missed with the opportunity attack. I then made a melee basic in response, which hit, and proceeded to shift 4 squares (I have the Mark of Passage). That shift took me past 2 other enemies for which I would've triggered opportunity attacks had I kept walking, then I moved the remaining 3 squares of my original move after the shift ended.

So, basically, can I take an opportunity action, in particular one that involves movement, in the middle of my move, and can I continue moving after I resolve that action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You could not have taken the opportunity action on your own turn**

You cannot take opportunity actions on your own turn, so if you, on your turn, move in such a way that your stance is triggered, you can't use the opportunity action granted by the stance.

Thus the question about movement interruption is a moot point, though in general interruptions are resolved in sequence.

For example: you have this opportunity action, and you also have an immediate interrupt that says "when an enemy moves adjacent to you, you can shift 3 squares."

1. An enemy attacks you.
2. You retaliate with your stance, and start to shift away, but as soon as you get 1 square away, another enemy uses an interrupt to shift adjacent to you.
3. You trigger your immediate interrupt and shift 3 squares away from the second enemy.
4. You now resume your shift form the opportunity action, shifting 2 more squares away from the first enemy.

**But, always remember: you cannot take opportunity or immediate actions (be they attacks, reactions, or interrupts) on your own turn!**